# Python script run via cron missing import

Tags: python, cron

I've recently created a Python script that I want to execute every day, using Cron. For testing it I'm trying to run it every minute and redirect the output to `injury.log`for testing.

My cron setup is just `*/1 * * * * python /root/path/to/script/update.py >> /var/log/injury.log 2>&1`

However in injury.log it's spitting back

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/reddit/sidebar/injury/update.py", line 1, in <module>
    from unidecode import unidecode
ImportError: No module named unidecode
```

Now I first started using unidecode in this script last night, and installed it using Pip, so I know it exists (even tried installing it again and was informed it's already there)

The script still executes fine manually, is there anything specific I need to include in my cron execution for it to recognize this?

I'm doing all of this as `root` too, so I don't believe it's a permissions error.

Comment: Is the `PYTHONPATH` correctly set?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I was able to get it working, the big issue was mostly my PATH variables.